# Stick jQuery UI dialog to side of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a simple way to "stick" a jQuery UI dialog to the side of the browser window so on window resize, the dialog remains stuck?

Comment: Have you tried the position option? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position

Comment: Can the user close the dialog?  Why would you want the dialog to stick to the side?  I think you could possibly using the dialog for the wrong purpose, but anyways, you can try using absolute positioning on the outer dialog div.

Comment: @j08691 With any position option, scrolling moves the dialog. I want the dialog to be *attached* to the window. This is almost what I want:
    create: function (event) {     $(event.target).parent().css({'position': 'fixed', 'right' : '0'});}

but when the browser window is resized, the dialog is detached from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the relative location (say, 50%), you'd use something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var divTop= ((document.body.scrollHeight/2)-$(mydiv).height()/2)
    $(mydiv).css({top: divTop; left: 0});
});
```

You'd drop code like that into the onLoad or onReady functions of your page.

For more info, check out the [jQuery Documentation on .resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and event handlers in general.